# Angular - How to bring variable from one component to another

Tags: html, angular

I'm pretty new to Angular 4 and am having some trouble with my program and being able to bring a variable from one component to another. I'm trying to bring the selectedEmployee variable from tracker.component.ts to my summary.component.html file and use it where I have it documented. My first thought would be to use routes but I'm not quite sure how to implement that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here's my tracker.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { SummaryComponent } from './summary.component';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-tracker',
    templateUrl: `./tracker.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.css']
})

export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit{
    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    isHidden: boolean = false;
    public selectedEmployee: number;

    constructor(private empInfoService: EmpInfoService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => this.empInfo = empInfo
        );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
    }

    toggleSummary(): void {
        this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    }
}
```

Here's my tracker.component.html:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-12':isHidden === true, 'col-xs-7': isHidden !== false}" style="background-color:red;">
    <button class="form-control" style="width:150px;" (click)="toggleSummary();gotoSummary()">Open Summary</button>
    <select id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee">
      <option selected="selected" disabled>Employee Name...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let emp of empInfo; let i = index" [value]="i">{{i}} - {{emp.EmpID}}</option>
    </select>
    <select id="PTOtype">
      <option selected="selected" disabled>Type of PTO...</option>
      <option value="PTO">PTO</option>
      <option value="ETO-Earned">ETO - Earned</option>
      <option value="ETO-Used">ETO - Used</option>
      <option value="STDLTD">STD/LTD</option>
      <option value="Uncharged">Uncharged</option>
    </select>
    <h2 *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">{{empInfo[selectedEmployee].FirstName}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isHidden" class="col-xs-5">
        <pto-summary></pto-summary>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my summary.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { TrackerComponent } from './tracker.component';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-summary',
    templateUrl: `./summary.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})

export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit{
    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    selectedIndex = 4;
    selectedEmployee: EmpInfo;

    timeVar = " hours";
    checkboxValue = false;

    constructor(private empInfoService: EmpInfoService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => this.empInfo = empInfo
        );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
    }

    onSelect(empInfo: EmpInfo): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = empInfo;
    }

    changeTime(): void {
        if (!this.checkboxValue)
        {
            this.timeVar = " hours"

            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].STDLTD = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].STDLTD * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].Uncharged = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].Uncharged * 8;

            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBase = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBase * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOCarry = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOCarry * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBorrowed = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBorrowed * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBalance = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBalance * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTORequests = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTORequests * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTORemaining = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTORemaining * 8;

            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETOEarned = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETOEarned * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETORequests = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETORequests * 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETORemaining = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETORemaining * 8;
        }
        else
        {
            this.timeVar = " days"

            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].STDLTD = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].STDLTD / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].Uncharged = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].Uncharged / 8;

            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBase = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBase / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOCarry = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOCarry / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBorrowed = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBorrowed / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBalance = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTOBalance / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTORequests = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTORequests / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTORemaining = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].PTORemaining / 8;

            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETOEarned = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETOEarned / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETORequests = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETORequests / 8;
            this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETORemaining = this.empInfo[this.selectedIndex].ETORemaining / 8;
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my summary.component.html:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">{{empInfo[selectedEmployee].LastName | uppercase}} Summary</h3>
    <div style="float: right;">
      <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input [(ngModel)]="checkboxValue" (change)="changeTime()" type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
          <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
          <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Status </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <select class="form-control" id="empStatus" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpStat" name="empStatus">
                <option value="Current">Current</option>
                <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Anniversary </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empAnniversary" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].Anniversary" name="empAnniversary"/>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Start Date </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empStartDate" [ngModel]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].StartDate | date: 'MM/dd/y'" name="empStartDate"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Adjusted Start </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empAdjustedStart" [ngModel]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].AdjustedStart | date: 'MM/dd/y'" name="empAdjustedStart"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> STD/LTD </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empSTDLTD" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].STDLTD + timeVar" name="empSTDLTD"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Uncharged </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empUncharged" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].Uncharged + timeVar" name="empUncharged"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>


      <fieldset>

        <h4>PTO</h4>
        <br />

        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-2"> Base </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBase" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTOBase + timeVar" name="ptoBase"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#43; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Carryover </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoCarry" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTOCarry + timeVar" name="ptoCarry"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Balance </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBalance" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTOBalance + timeVar" name="ptoBalance"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Borrowed </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBorrowed" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTOBorrowed + timeVar" name="ptoBorrowed"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Requests </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoRequests" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTORequests + timeVar" name="ptoRequests"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Balance </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBalance" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTOBalance + timeVar" name="ptoBalance"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
            <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Available </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoRemaining" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].PTORemaining + timeVar" name="ptoRemaining"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>


      <fieldset>

        <h4>ETO</h4>
        <br />

          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
              <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Earned </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoEarned" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].ETOEarned + timeVar" name="etoEarned"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
              <label class="col-xs-2"> &#8213; </label>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Requests </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="etoRequests" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].ETORequests + timeVar" name="etoRequests"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
              <label class="col-xs-2"> &#61; </label>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Available </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoRemaining" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedEmployee].ETORemaining + timeVar" name="etoRemaining"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6"></div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the `selectedEmployee` in `tracker.component.ts` is not same type as the one in `summary.component.ts`. If that's the case, create a new variable in `tracker.component.ts` which is an `Input`.

```
@Input() employeeSelectedInSummary;
```

In `my tracker.component.html` do following:

```
<pto-summary [employeeSelectedInSummary]="selectedEmployee"></pto-summary>
```

Note: Make sure you have imported the `Input` from `@angular/core`.

Comment: It should be `@Input()`

Comment: Don't forget to import input from @angular/core on top of the summary component